# Remove '^@' line from a file

Tags: sed, ascii, binaryfiles, nano

I have a file in which I have a particular line of this type:

`^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^ ...`

Actually all the others lines are a list (a matrix) of numbers or `*******`. The problem is that I can not be able to open this [file](http://speedy.sh/ePrjY/fort.21.dat) with normal editors and so I can not be able to remove this line.

I can open the file via shell using `nano`.

To eliminate this line (that is the second line from the top) I used the simple command:

`sed '2d' fort.21.dat`

But I can not be able to eliminate it.

Can someone help me to eliminate this line and make this file.dat normally readable ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Those characters are how a nul byte are displayed, meaning it's a binary file.  `.dat` implies it is a binary data file too. Are you sure you're meant to be able to open it with a normal text editor?

Comment: You realise that your `sed` command doesn't actually change the file, right? It will print the modified data to stdout, not back to the file. Use `sed -i .bak 2d fort.21.dat` to edit the file in-place, or `sed 2d fort.21.dat > fort.21.txt` to write it to a new file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
tr -d '\0' < fort.21.dat > fixed.21.dat
```

This uses the `tr` utility to delete the `^@` (zero) bytes from the file.